# Updating baseURI not working in FA2

Tags: smartpy, nft, fa2

I have been working on a Worker contract which is the parent of an NFT contract. The NFT contract is used to create dynamic NFTs (by changing their baseURI) in the contract and accessing the tokens using customized off-chain view.

I have created a new NFT with a baseURI ([ipfs://bafybeibefpopll3oljhqysx3mbq6647zcrbiuhae4owtu2xn2mk4lbprty](https://bafybeibefpopll3oljhqysx3mbq6647zcrbiuhae4owtu2xn2mk4lbprty.ipfs.dweb.link/)) and minted it. The contract address of NFT is **KT1Rvp4pjFct1aWHKT7GSqnj3PvHD45AZCFj** and that of Worker contract is **KT1JgdTSpT2tSecmBqd3gquqnfLbGMnsmFfY**. When I changed the baseURI to [ipfs://bafybeicyoqmddy5ixuzj3jov4i6vjpnchefxi5huxti6xirgkwrzlnvuqe](https://bafybeicyoqmddy5ixuzj3jov4i6vjpnchefxi5huxti6xirgkwrzlnvuqe.ipfs.dweb.link/), even then the token was showing the older metadata on objkt.

Both contracts are deployed on mainnet.

I am getting the updated token_metadata in token_metadata off-chain view.

You can check out the minted nft [here](https://objkt.com/asset/KT1Rvp4pjFct1aWHKT7GSqnj3PvHD45AZCFj/0). The nft should display the artifact uri of a flower now but it is still showing a landscape.

Can someone help me on how to get the updated token_metadata and what is the issue.